# Is labeled Break and labeled Continue are identical in functionality?

Tags: java

I know for sure the functionality of normal break and continue are different to each other. But when label is used these functionality seems identical. Is it not ambiguous to support these ambiguous statements in java language?

```
label1:
for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("My Message one");

        break label1;

        System.out.println("My Message two");
    }
}

label2:
for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("My Message one");

        continue label2;

        System.out.println("My Message two");
    }
}
```

Comment: Atleast not post code with errors apart from the problem you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same.

A labeled break exits the named loop immediately. A labeled continue ends the current iteration, but does not exit the loop unless its guard condition fails. This is exactly analogous to regular break and continue statements.

```
break label1;
```

This immediately exits the outer loop.

```
continue label2;
```

This exits the inner loop and goes to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are absolutely not identical in functionality.

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
test1: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sb1.append("test: " + i);
    for (int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
        if (j == 10) {
            break test1;
        }
    }
}
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
test2: for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sb2.append("test: " + i);
    for (int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
        if (j == 10) {
            continue test2;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString()));
```

Output is

```
false
```